# Can't access Rust web servers on same wifi but can access nodejs and python web server on same wifi

Tags: node.js, macos, visual-studio-code, rust, networking

**UPDATE:** For unknown reason, I just restarted my Mac mini and it has magically started working. Both Axum and Actix servers are now accessible from my iPhone and Windows. Not sure what changed.

I have been facing a weird issue for last couple days and unable to figure out the root cause. I have done quite a lot of troubleshooting on this.

I have a Mac mini running macOS Sonoma 14.1.2 on which I am doing my development work. On the same wifi network, I have an iPhone (iOS 17.3) and a Windows 10 laptop.

Mac has IP address `192.168.50.150`

iPhone has IP address `192.168.50.196`

Windows has IP address `192.168.50.169`

iPhone and Windows are able to successfully ping the Mac.

MacOS's firewall is OFF on Mac.

I am doing development on the Mac using VS Code and I run the code using the VS Code Terminal.

On my Mac, when I run a simple web server built in Rust with the following code:

```
use axum::routing::get;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {

    let app = axum::Router::new()
    .route("/", get(root));

    let listener = tokio::net::TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:23232").await.unwrap();
    axum::serve(listener, app).await.unwrap();
}

async fn root() -> &'static str {
    "Hello from Rust"
}
```

Then I am able to access the website from the Mac itself using `http://192.168.50.150:23232/` but **unable to access it from both the iPhone and Windows.**

But if I switch off this Rust server and use the following simple nodejs server:

```
const express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.send("Hello from nodejs");
});
app.listen(23232, function () {
    console.log("Running!");
});
```

Then I am able to access the same website from all devices at the exact same url.

Similarly, if I run a simple python web server using command:

```
python3 -m http.server 23232
```

I am also able to access this from all devices at the exact same url.

Instead of Axum, I also tried Actix and that also doesn't work:

```
use actix_web::{get, App, HttpServer, Responder};

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| App::new().service(index))
        .bind(":::23232")?
        .run()
        .await
}

#[get("/")]
async fn index() -> impl Responder {
    "Hello from Rust Actix"
}
```

So issue seems to be specific to Rust web servers.

When running Rust server, netstat output is:

```
netstat -anvp tcp | awk 'NR<3 || /LISTEN/' | grep 23232
tcp4       0      0  *.23232                *.*                    LISTEN       131072  131072  40257      0 00100 00000006 0000000003722a35 00000001 00000900      1      0 000001
```

When running Nodejs server, netstat output is:

```
netstat -anvp tcp | awk 'NR<3 || /LISTEN/' | grep 23232
tcp46      0      0  *.23232                *.*                    LISTEN       131072  131072  40190      0 00100 00000106 000000000371c15d 00000001 00000800      1      0 000001
```

The only difference I notice is `tcp46` at the beginning of the nodejs netstat compared to `tcp4` for Rust. So I changed the Rust bind to `":::23232"`. This changed netstat output to:

```
netstat -anvp tcp | awk 'NR<3 || /LISTEN/' | grep 23232
tcp46      0      0  *.23232                *.*                    LISTEN       131072  131072  40310      0 00100 00000006 000000000372444a 00000001 00000800      1      0 000001
```

But I am still unable to access it from the iPhone and Windows.

I have tried running the Rust build in both debug and release version but problem persists.

**IMPORTANT:**

One thing I have noticed and I think is important is that if I turn off the Rust server entirely, then when I access the website, then I get an instant browser error that:

iPhone: `Safari can't open the page because it couldn't connect to the server.`

and

Windows: `This site can't be reached. 192.168.50.150 refused to connect.`

However, when I start the Rust server again, it's not instant. In fact, both iPhone and Windows keep trying to load it and I get a spinner on Windows and "stop loading cross button" on iPhone. It takes a few seconds for it to time out.

On Windows, in the browser inspector tab's Network tab, I see a `Pending` until it eventually times out.

When it does timeout on Windows, the browser has a `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` in the error.

However, when Rust server is turned off, the browser has a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in the error instead.

What could be the cause here? Any other troubleshooting steps I can take?

**EDIT:** I ran tcpdump while running Rust server on the Mac and I can see incoming traffic from the iPhone but no outgoing traffic:

```
username@Mac-Mini release % sudo tcpdump -v host 192.168.50.196
tcpdump: data link type PKTAP
tcpdump: listening on pktap, link-type PKTAP (Apple DLT_PKTAP), snapshot length 524288 bytes
16:23:41.904147 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    iphone13device.52734 > Mac-Mini.23232: Flags [S], cksum 0xfec2 (correct), seq 3206597604, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3392000923 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
16:23:42.847989 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    iphone13device.52734 > Mac-Mini.23232: Flags [S], cksum 0xfad5 (correct), seq 3206597604, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3392001928 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
16:23:43.894933 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    iphone13device.52734 > Mac-Mini.23232: Flags [S], cksum 0xf6e8 (correct), seq 3206597604, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3392002933 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
16:23:44.858587 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    iphone13device.52734 > Mac-Mini.23232: Flags [S], cksum 0xf2fa (correct), seq 3206597604, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3392003939 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
16:23:45.897660 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    iphone13device.52734 > Mac-Mini.23232: Flags [S], cksum 0xef0d (correct), seq 3206597604, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3392004944 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
16:23:46.869274 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    iphone13device.52734 > Mac-Mini.23232: Flags [S], cksum 0xeb20 (correct), seq 3206597604, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3392005949 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
16:23:48.969658 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    iphone13device.52734 > Mac-Mini.23232: Flags [S], cksum 0xe34a (correct), seq 3206597604, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3392007955 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
16:23:52.963233 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    iphone13device.52734 > Mac-Mini.23232: Flags [S], cksum 0xd3a5 (correct), seq 3206597604, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3392011960 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
16:24:00.884611 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    iphone13device.52734 > Mac-Mini.23232: Flags [S], cksum 0xb460 (correct), seq 3206597604, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3392019965 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

Same tcpdump output when running nodejs server on Mac:

```
username@Mac-Mini release % sudo tcpdump -v host 192.168.50.196
tcpdump: data link type PKTAP
tcpdump: listening on pktap, link-type PKTAP (Apple DLT_PKTAP), snapshot length 524288 bytes
16:27:16.634487 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    iphone13device.52736 > Mac-Mini.23232: Flags [S], cksum 0x7e01 (correct), seq 416291912, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 20607804 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
16:27:16.634675 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has iphone13device tell Mac-Mini, length 28
16:27:16.941567 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply iphone13device is-at 24:5e:48:8c:5c:2c (oui Unknown), length 28
16:27:16.941592 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    Mac-Mini.23232 > iphone13device.52736: Flags [S.], cksum 0xbc43 (correct), seq 3459470414, ack 416291913, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 187077636 ecr 20607804,sackOK,eol], length 0
16:27:16.946637 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    iphone13device.52736 > Mac-Mini.23232: Flags [.], cksum 0xf2ab (correct), ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 20608154 ecr 187077636], length 0
16:27:16.946686 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    Mac-Mini.23232 > iphone13device.52736: Flags [.], cksum 0xf172 (correct), ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 187077949 ecr 20608154], length 0
16:27:16.947930 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 451)
    iphone13device.52736 > Mac-Mini.23232: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9d6c (correct), seq 1:400, ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 20608154 ecr 187077636], length 399
16:27:16.947965 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    Mac-Mini.23232 > iphone13device.52736: Flags [.], cksum 0xefe8 (correct), ack 400, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 187077950 ecr 20608154], length 0
16:27:16.957461 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 297)
    Mac-Mini.23232 > iphone13device.52736: Flags [P.], cksum 0x4894 (correct), seq 1:246, ack 400, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 187077959 ecr 20608154], length 245
16:27:16.961364 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    iphone13device.52736 > Mac-Mini.23232: Flags [.], cksum 0xeed8 (correct), ack 246, win 2055, options [nop,nop,TS val 20608169 ecr 187077959], length 0
16:27:19.395989 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    iphone13device.52736 > Mac-Mini.23232: Flags [.], cksum 0x3e42 (correct), ack 246, win 2055, length 0
16:27:19.396038 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    Mac-Mini.23232 > iphone13device.52736: Flags [.], cksum 0xe554 (correct), ack 400, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 187080398 ecr 20608169], length 0
```

Comment: My instinct is that node is listening to `192.168.50.150:23232` and `127.0.0.1:23232`, while rust is only listening to `127.0.0.1:23232`. I don't know why the localhost one doesn't also work for the LAN, but I've had this problem before.

Comment: After reading a little bit I still think this is the problem, but I don't know why 0.0.0.0 doesn't give you LAN access.

Comment: @drewtato since I am using 0.0.0.0, I don't think that should be the issue. My netstat output shows *:23232 which also shows that. Am I wrong?

Comment: What does `route -n` report on the Mac?

Comment: @Jmb it says `usage: route [-dnqtv] command [[modifiers] args]`. Which arguments should I pass?

Comment: @sudoExclamationExclamation on Linux, calling simply `route` would list the current routing table (and `-n` disables name resolution). I don't know the Mac equivalent, but I would assume something like `route -n show` or `route -n list` should do it.

Comment: @Jmb For unknown reason, I just restarted my Mac mini and it has magically started working. Both Axum and Actix servers are now accessible from my iPhone and Windows. Not sure what changed.

Comment: @sudoExclamationExclamation I suspect there was a wrong route in your routing table and that for some reason the Rust programs were using that route when sending replies instead of the correct one. Rebooting the Mac mini has reset the routing table, allowing the replies to be sent to the correct destination.